# Parsing and loading XML data from a URL

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I need to get XML data from this particular address (https://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.xml). But when I run the application, nothing happens. Also honestly I do not know how to get from the above xml id 1, id 2 and so on. I'll be happy for any of your advice. Thx

```
- (id)initWithArray: (NSMutableArray *)slovoArray {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.slovoArray = slovoArray;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)parseXMLFile
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.xml"];

    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
      self.parser.delegate = self;
     [self.parser parse];  
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([_element isEqualToString:@"radek"]) {

        _item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.kod   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.kurz    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"kod"])
    {
        [self.kod appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"kurz"])
    {
        [self.kurz appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"radek"]) {
        Slova *thisSlovo = [[Slova alloc] initWithName:self.kod
                                              kurz:self.kurz];
        [self.slovoArray addObject:thisSlovo];
    }
    self.element = nil; 
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"Enter Here your webservice url" ];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSURLResponse* response;
  NSError* error;
 NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *  rsltStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSError *parseError = nil;
 NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:rsltStr error:&parseError];  // In this I have used XMLReader file
```

Download XML Reader file from here : -   [XML Reader Download](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader)

For more help about XMLReader Visit here :- [**SOAP webservice calling in iOS with xml parsing**](http://www.jogendra.com/2015/03/soap-webservice-calling-in-ios-with-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

To read XML data from URLs, I recently wrote a simple XML parser for iOS called ConiferXML that might do what you're looking for. You can check it out at [GitHub](http://www.github.com/coniferapps/coniferxml). If this doesn't work out there is also another library on [GitHub](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) that is a little more complex but does the same thing.